# EF6 core : The Collation specified by SQL Server is not supported. - Hungarian_Technical_CI_AS

Tags: exception, .net-core, entity-framework-6, collation

I moved our project from EF5 to EF6 today, and the repository which worked fined - now drops "The Collation specified by SQL Server is not supported." during a query.

Our database currently uses "Hungarian_Technical_CI_AS" as collation.

I also tried to re-create the model:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold 
  "Server=<ourServerName>;Database=<OurDatabaseName>;Integrated Security=True" 
  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer  
  -o EF.Legacy  -c OurContextName -n Infrastructure.SQL.EF.Legacy -f
```

It also drops the error at the end of the execution.

What should I do?

The log is:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The Collation specified by SQL Server is not supported.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs:line 1853
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlInternalConnection.cs:line 611
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs:line 1327
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs:line 2550
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs:line 1847
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.DrainData(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs:line 4451
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowUnsupportedCollationEncountered(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs:line 4467
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadStringWithEncoding(Int32 length, Encoding encoding, Boolean isPlp, String& value) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserStateObject.cs:line 1772
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlStringValue(SqlBuffer value, Byte type, Int32 length, Encoding encoding, Boolean isPlp, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs:line 5604
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, SqlCommandColumnEncryptionSetting columnEncryptionOverride, String columnName) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs:line 6023
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i, Boolean readHeaderOnly) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs:line 3782
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs:line 3626
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs:line 3607
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs:line 2618
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.GetTables(DbConnection connection, DatabaseModel databaseModel, Func`3 tableFilter, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 typeAliases, String databaseCollation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection connection, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluarlize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:76fdc33d-58a9-4194-b945-13ff6b785556
The Collation specified by SQL Server is not supported.
```

Comment: You need to wait for .NET 6.0.2

Comment: Nice! How do you know that may I ask?! :)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1396